# How to call a function after 5 seconds?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to call a function `executeAfter5secs()` in my `home.ts` when `home.html` is opened. How do I do this ?

Currently I have added a button on `home.html` and on click of it, the function is being called, but I want to be free from the click and want to call it automatically once the page is loaded, **but after 5 seconds.**

How do I code in `home.ts` side, I am bit confused like what do I code inside:

```
ngOnInit() {    }
```

so that once page is loader time starts and after 5 seconds my function is called.

Comment: setTimeout( ()=>{console.log('works') }, 5000);

Answer (score 26):

Add this code in your **.ts** file

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        alert('Hello...')
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: what you have modified from my answer.?

Comment: @PrasanthS Your answer is fine, but you're using Angular `AfterViewInit` but you've not explained from where the op imports it. Also @AddWeb is using an Ionic lifecycle hook, that is better when using Ionic (be cause many tutorials use it) and need less code.

Comment: actually he try to acheive in 'ngOnInit()',

Answer (score 15):

you need to use 'AfterViewInit' after component's view fully initialized.

in .ts file

```
export class LoginPage implements AfterViewInit {

ngAfterViewInit(){
   setTimeout( ()=>{
   console.log('works')
   }, 5000)
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.startTrackingLoop();
}
ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.stopTrackingLoop();
}

startTrackingLoop() {
    this.tracking = setInterval(() => {
        //run code
    }, 5000);
}
stopTrackingLoop() {
    clearInterval(this.tracking);
    this.tracking = null;
}
```

Comment: no need interval here, need to just call one time, `settimeout` is the right choice here